# How can I erase drawings on imageview without changing the Image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, uiimageview

My requirement is to erase the specific drawing on ImageView without affecting the image; in my case when I apply eraser on image, the whole image is also changing with drawings on ImageView [I want to erase only drawings].

NOTE:for eraser functionality I used a white color.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 image views and 2 images. The base image will be your body outline. Have the user draw into the second image, which you would draw on top of the first. When the user erases, erase the second, top image.

(Erase to clear, not white)

Comment: if we apply clear total drawing pattern will deleting  ,i want to erase the some part of drawing.plz can u provide any sample code .